# How to make a texture disappear when a mesh passes over it? Like vacuuming dirt from a carpet.

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, texturing, materials

I have a carpet texture and I added a lot of dirt on top of it. How do I make the the parts where the vacuum goes to disappear? This is for cycles.

Comment: Have you looked into Dynamic paint? Looks like the right feature for what you want to do https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/dynamic_paint/index.html